# bundle remote error: Repository not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I want deploy the sample project of rails3 in action.When i run 'bundle install',it tells me that remote error: Repository not found.I am new to git,github and rails3.but i have alreay created a github account and config git and github well.i do not know what happend.i will be very thankful if anything can help!

Here is the console message(ubuntu 12.04LST):

magic@magic-ThinkPad-T430u:~/文档/rails/ticketee-book$ bundle

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Fetching git://github.com/radar/rack-test
fatal: remote error: Repository not found.
Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/radar/rack-test'
"/home/magic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3.2/cache/bundler/git/rack-test-
8ce034d275474b0b137179c1bd5be3e5ee2e2464" 
--bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /home/magic/文档/rails/ticketee-book has failed.
```

Here is the gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', :git => "git://github.com/rails/rails", :branch => "3-1-stable"
# gem 'arel',      :git => 'git://github.com/rails/arel.git'
gem 'rack'
gem 'sprockets', :git => "git://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets.git"

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'sass', '~> 3.1.0.alpha'
gem 'coffee-script'

gem 'dynamic_form'

gem 'devise', :git => "git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git"
gem 'cancan'

gem 'paperclip', :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"

gem 'searcher'
gem 'kaminari'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "oa-oauth", :require => "omniauth/oauth"
gem "delayed_job"

# gem "forem", :git => "git://github.com/radar/forem"
gem "ticketee-forem", :require => "forem", :path => "../forem"

gem 'sinatra'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'gmail'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.6.1.beta1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rack-test', :git => "git://github.com/radar/rack-test"
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :git => "git://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails"
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'launchy'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Gemfile`, in the `test` group, you have the following line

```
gem 'rack-test', :git => "git://github.com/radar/rack-test"
```

It will instruct bundler to clone the repository and use its contents as a gem. As the repository doesn't exist on Github anymore, the `bundle` fails.

You should edit your Gemfile and either use the new repository location or use the published gem from `rubygems.org`. In the end, you have to edit your gemfile to use one of the following alternatives:

```
gem 'rack-test', :git => "https://github.com/brynary/rack-test.git"
# or
gem "rack-test"
```

Comment: yes,i thought a lot and guess the repository might be outdated.It seems so.thank u

Answer (score 0):

No, the problem is that the repository is not there anymore. try by downloading repository on a new address:

```
git clone git://github.com/brynary/rack-test.git
```

Now after cloning has done, in terminal do:

```
cd rack-test
```

And now you are in `very` directory you created when you did `git clone` and then try to run command:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

And everything should work

Comment: I download the source code of Rails3 in Action and in its dir.I run the 'bundle' command and then occured the problem.So i do not konw what happend exactly.i guess the git clone was somewhere in the gemfile.So i don't konw which dir created by the git clone.Anyway,thank u very much.Can u tell me more?

Comment: ok, you downloaded the source code in action. What does `action` mean? But regardless, can you tell me in which directory have you downloaded the source code? When you did git clone - it created a new directory in the directory where you have run git clone

Comment: sorry,i didn't get that cleary.The book's name is "Rails3 in Action".I download the source code and want to get it deployed and running.

Comment: can you try with approach I have put in the answer, and tell me whether it worked and what the problem is

Comment: The source code is a rails3 project.'~/文档/rails/ticketee-book' is the root dir of the project.Under the root dir,i run the bundle command which will read the gemfile in this dir and excute it.I didn't run 'git clone' while i guess is in the gemfile.But i tried what u said,if i run 'git clone' under the root dir of the project, it get the same error.If i run 'bundle install --path vendor/bundle' ,it same too.

Comment: yes, but I have `never` said to run `git clone` under the root dir of the project. Ok, so you run `bundle install` when you are in `~/文档/rails/ticketee-book` directory - is that right?

Comment: @magic_cwin ok, I have updated the answer. I can see now what your problem is